# Feature: notification/overview for comment upvotes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, voting

I really like the comment-functionality. Comments are a great way of asking/providing information on a question/answer. I make a lot of comments. They can be upvoted. I get the reason behind it. Upvotes mean consensus. But I would find it nice to be able to track how a comment of mine is faring without revisiting the question.

My request:

- Either notify my when a comment is upvoted (like 9GAG does).
- Or a overview page in which you can see upvoted comments, like questions/answers.

The first option can cause flooding, however it can be grouped, like it is done now in the achievements menu. Since comments are more widely used then answers a user should be able to turn the feature of to prevent flooding.

Comment: What action would you take on a comment of yours being up-voted?

Comment: Just for the fun of it or to see if an opinion of mine is valid. I'm not taking actions to upvoted answers to.

Comment: But you're not notified (to your inbox) of upvoted answers, either. You're notified on comments and edits. Changes in reputation are separated, and since comments have no affect on reputation putting it in the "Achievements" section just seems like it'd be wasting space for something that the vast majority of people looking there won't care about.

Comment: I'm declining this because it would be far too noisy and I see no actual benefit to this feature.

Answer (score 7):

I am not in favor of this as comments are meant to be temporary and can be deleted at any moment.  I don't think SE needs to spends development time on implementing features for temporary things.  If you want to see how your comments are doing you can run this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109328/my-highest-rated-comments) that was provided by [Mysticial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/169611/mysticial) in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177225/291223).  As [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) pointed out you could also use the API from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177224/291223) that [juergen d](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/172011/juergen-d) provided and use the link

```
 https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/user_number/comments?order=desc&min=5&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow
```

Comment: even better: use the API from the answer from [juergen d](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177224/158100) (I just updated it to work for the 2.2 api)

Comment: Thanks @rene.  I have included it the answer