# The "I'm a human" - checker speaks Portuguese

Tags: support, internationalization

This is now fixed for me. I now see `Type the text` (and without changing country or using an international internet-provider). A couple of other confirmations and perhaps we can get a status-complete?

---

I went to run the SEDE query, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109328/my-highest-rated-comments, from this answer, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302147/1927206.

When I try to run it ("first time") it says `introduza o texto` when it presents the Captcha box to me. All the other text on the page is in English.

I am in Portugal. I did visit Stack Overflow em Português this morning. But, my OS and Browser are entirely in English.

I have used that query before, and it didn't speak Portuguese to me then. I think.

[image]

Comment: It's not related to the Portuguese SO. For me it displays a text in Dutch. If the devs haven't specified a language for reCAPTCHA, it automatically chooses a language to use.

Comment: @Stijn Thanks. I'm pretty sure I'd have noticed before. But I could be wrong... If I visit Vietnam some time, I'm going to be seriously confused. OK, I'm not, I know what goes there.

Comment: @Will I could feel that edit coming as I was typing the tag-name. I'm sure there should be a tag, and I wouldn't care how it was spelled, but if I had to create it (which I didn't realise I could), why would it not have my, correct also, in a different locale, spelling? Irony, thy name is internacionalização

Comment: I actually didn't mean to edit, one of my user scripts did :) It's configured for SO, where the Z spelling is the accepted one, so any S spellings result in a fragmented tag.  I suppose I could restrict the domain better for the script, but since this is Meta.SO, I'd say the tags should probably match...

Comment: Speaking Portuguese? Is the "I'm a human" checker also human?

Comment: Just to make your day a little more interesting.

Comment: Per Firefox's Network inspector, this text is pulled in from http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge - so you are at the mercy of Google to determine the language.  The odd thing is, I have my browser/locale set to Welsh, and Google.com shows Welsh, but the recaptcha box shows English (I am in the US right now).  It looks like it may be entirely Geo-IP based.

Comment: @AndrewWilcox looking forward to visiting Wales. Is the box big enough for the text?

Comment: Can anyone, recollect seeing the text in that box in the past? I'd like to think I'd have noticed it last time. 99% sure, but that's useless Anyone for definite know?

Comment: Adding &hl=en to captcha request should fix this.

Comment: My OS and browser, and my street name all are in English and if recaptha is going to suggest me a Portuguese captha when on a tour to Mediterranean, then i have to buy one of those keyboards there with all special characters, or add a portuguese soft keyboard usually suggested for a disabled person :-| . I should think thrice travelling east asia :-)

Answer (score 67):

Recaptcha is supplied by google.

Google, in their infinite wisdom, believe that a person using the web in a given country is much more likely to want to use one of the languages commonly used in that country, rather than a language that you can actually read and write as indicated by their `Accept-Language` which is based on the browser settings, which by default is based on their OS settings. (It's often not as bad if you're logged into google when you access the services).

Maybe google just want to help people acclimatise to their surroundings.

There is a `&hl=en` option that SO could use to suggest maybe English might be a good language to use here.

Comment: So, "no matter the language of the rest of the page, use a language related to estimated geographic location" would about sum it up? If I go near the border, connect to a Spanish provider, it'll give me in Spanish (Andalusian)? Yes, that is an idea resonating infinite wisdom from Google :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger just as pretty much any other Google service if you provide the `hl` parameter Google uses it so I don't see how that is a problem of Google's infinite wisdom, rather than an issue in how the tool they provide is being used. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: @nico that link gets me "Optional. Forces the widget to render in a specific language. Auto-detects the user's language if unspecified." The method of auto-detecting the user's language seems "wisdomic" to me.

Comment: Classic Google.

Comment: @nico Because without such a hl parameter surely it should use the user's language to decide the user's language, no?

Comment: @JonHanna how they choose the language is a completely different matter. Here we always want to have it in English, so the issue is not how Google chooses the language, which I agree may not be optimal sometimes (although it still probably work for the majority of people), it's the hl parameter being missing that is the issue. Unless this is a thread about whining about Google's services, then those comments are highly appropriate.

Comment: @nico If they'd a sensible mechanism, then the result would be either that specified by the site (which it certainly should do anyway) or one that the user can understand. It wouldn't be as big a problem as it currently is.

Comment: `Maybe google just want to help people acclimatise to their surroundings.` <--- so nice of them :)

Comment: @tacone You don't say. Recently, I've received a banner at Wikia written in Japanese(!) (while I'm in European Russia). I understand that anime is quite popular here and all, but to proclaim that they have totally conquered us is a bit premature ;)

Comment: Yep, ran into a similar thing years back where Google wanted to force me to search in the language of where my IP was from, despite my computer's settings, Chrome's settings, and my Google account settings. (There ended up being one specific setting somewhere that they actually respected; I forget which.) To be fair, I know many people where I was had computers running pirated Windows in a language they couldn't read. I wonder if Google was thinking of those sorts of users.

Comment: @DanGetz hmm. That would suggest that there were more people who were running illegal copies of their OS AND also didn't know how to change their browser language AND the OS was in a language foreign to them, than there are people who have a legitimate copy of their OS OR know how to change their browser language and are in a country where they don't read one of the primary languages. If that was the case it would certainly be an interesting statistic.

Comment: @JonHanna well, add a lot of computer illiteracy, a little actual illiteracy, and the fact that, even when literate, users don't read.